# Better architecture to outsource resource-intensive work to another program

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, jboss, architecture

I want to find a better architecture for sending commands to another program which handles resource-intensive work.

**Our current workflow**

We have a JBoss Server (Java EE6 Jboss 7.1.3) which creates a command file for another program. The other one is started with stdin parameters from the JBoss contex, which is reading the command file what to do. During the job the server gets messages that a certain item was handled. If the job is finished (e.g. create 300 Word documents with content, or calling webservices) the Server gets notified over RMI.

**New requirements**

The worker program should now be placed on a different machine. Also the calling should be over tcp. It should be possible to have a few instances which will be working on different jobs (or even machines). This program(s) must also be always running.

Are the any frameworks in java which supports this kind of workflow?
How would you do it? Would you use RMI or Sockets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sockets to communicate and use a native software on the servers performing the work.
There are no good frameworks handling this topic because it is very application specific. Write something like this: https://gist.github.com/Doralitze/fa3f81640da4be046b40

You can write the remote software in any language you want but I would recommend c++. It is also possible to write the software in java (but I would really recommend to compile it nativly using gcj). Anyway (if you decide for c++) you should use compiler flags to optimize your code to maximum performance and enable cpu specific optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of common approaches is [jmx/mbeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/mbeans/) or JMS.

Note: Spring makes it very easy to publish a bean as an mbean. More info [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jmx.html)

Another note for mbeans is that jconsole (part of the jdk) has an [mbeans plugin](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/jconsole/JConsole-plugin.html) (requires installation). This is helpful for debugging and can also be used in production to invoke methods.